# Grx 10 speed problem

Tags: shifter, road, brake-levers, gravel

I have a new 10 speed grx group set. The right hand shifter have only 9 gear. I check the problem is in lever,i felt in high gear it was making a big jump.
Are there any suggestions for someone who is having a similar problem??

Comment: Is the right hand shifter new, part of the groupset purchase?  Does the lever have 9 "clicks" ?  What is the shimano part number of the right shifter ?  Will look something like "ST-RX400"

Comment: New, ST-RX400-R, yes there are 9 clicks

Comment: A 10 speed shifter will have 9 clicks *between* gears and 10 gear positions. You need to observe what's going on at the derailleur to figure out what the problem is. With the rear wheel off the ground change gears across the cassette. What sprockets is the chain landing on? Edit your question to include this info.

Answer (score 1):

@ArgentiApparatus is correct - 9 clicks is 10 speeds.  Your lever starts at one end, in a gear position, and the first click puts it into the second position.  Thus there is one fewer click than gear positions.

You definitely have a 10 speed shifter, confirmed by  https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/grx-10-speed/ST-RX400-R.html

There remains the possibility that the shifter is somehow faulty, or that your indexing is not correct.